# Get percentage of used vocabulary (from table with words) in table with senteces

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my SQL: database with thousands of sentences and words database with thousands of words. The thing I want do is count percentage of used vocabulary in **sentences database** when vocabulary is in **words database**. For example if words sentence database contained records:

[image]

and words database contained records:

[image]

It would return 50% of used vocabulary. Is there a simple way to do that with SQL? I have already REGEXP pattern to check if the sentence contains specific word: `"\b$word\b[^']"`.

Comment: Do you need the total percentage "all words in all sentences"? Or per sentense?

Comment: *I have already REGEXP pattern to check if the sentence contains specific word:* What does `[^']` do in your pattern?

Comment: @Akina I need total percentage

Comment: @Akina In this way it doesn't query "don't" when you search "don", I think it doesn't matter in this question

Answer (score 1):

This is a *simple* way, but it is not efficient:

```
select count(*) / (select count(*) from words)
from words w 
where exists (select 1
              from sentences s
              where s.sentence regexp concat('\b', w.word, '\b[^']')
             );
```

Note:  Constructing the string literals may be a little tricky depending on how you are calling the query.  You may need `\\` for instance instead of `\`.

Comment: Slashes in string literals must be doubled. And `[^']` seems to be removed (or, if it is correct, then a quote must be doubled).

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

In my query if a word appear twice in a sentence, it will be count only once.

```
SELECT 

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM sentences s
CROSS JOIN words w
WHERE LOWER(s.sentence) LIKE CONCAT('%', LOWER(w.word), '%'))

/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words) * 100 AS percentage
```

This way it considered all appearance each word in each sentence:

```
SELECT 

(SELECT SUM(ROUND((LENGTH(s.sentence) - LENGTH(REPLACE(s.sentence, w.word, ""))) / LENGTH(w.word)))
FROM sentences s
CROSS JOIN words w
WHERE s.sentence REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', w.word, '[[:>:]]'))

/

(SELECT count(*) FROM words) * 100 AS percentage
```